# Bundling getopt_long() with my own code?

Tags: c, getopt, getopt-long

I have my own C project on github. I want to add long-option support by using GNU `getopt_long()` (which has it's own git repository). I believe there are 4 ways I can do this:

1. Use a [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).
2. Use a [git subtree](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html).
3. Import the source of the current (2.22.6) snapshot into my own git repository.
4. Import *only* the `getopt_long()` source files of `getopt.c`, `getopt1.c`, and `gnugetopt.h`.

The advantage of 1 and 2 is that I track `getopt_long()`. The advantages of 3 and 4 are that if the git repository of `getopt_long()` moves, it wont break my repository *and* it's much simpler to do.

Is there a recommended "GNU way" to do this?

Comment: Why import the source at all and not use a library?

Comment: Because it's not on all platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more Googl'ing, I found [the official GNU answer](http://www.gnu.org/software/gengetopt/gengetopt.html#Use-automake_002fautoconf).

Briefly, there are two recommended approaches:

## Use Gnulib (the "new" way)

Using the `gnulib-tool` command, one imports `getopt` to compile it as a subset of the GNU library by making a few tweaks to one's `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` files.

## Use `getopt_long` sources (the "old" way)

Import the `getopt_long` sources of `getopt.c`, `getopt1.c`, and `gnugetopt.h` and use the `adl_func_getopt_long.m4` macro to test for the existence of `getopt_long` on the platform and compile the imported sources only if necessary.